# How to store lists of options in a web application

Tags: php, database, laravel

We are currently designing a new database and I'm not sure how I want to store my lists of options.

For example, if you have a list of priorities:

```
1  High
2  Medium
3  Low
```

or type:

```
1 email
2 phone
3 text
```

How should I be storing these?

Historically I have placed them in a database table ( Option 1):

**Priorities**

```
id description
1  High
2  Medium
3  Low
```

The result of this, is that they become foreign keys in other tables.

An alternative (Option 2), is to store them in code, as a list of constants.

## Pros and Cons

### Option 1

- Much easier to maintain, no need to push code. You just add maintenance pages to edit the tables.
- Many more database hits, every time you want to retrieve the list.

### Option 2

- Less hits on the db.
- If the list need to be modified, you need to change the code and then push the code.

Have I missed anything? What is common practise?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would decide based on following factors :

**1. Number of available values :**

If it's just a set of 2 or 3 predefined values like priorities `High`, `Medium`, `Low`.. I would prefer to have it in codebase as constants. Because it is highly unlikely any new option will be added like `very low` or `very very low` etc

If the values are predefined but large in numbers, like maybe skillsets of an employee.. I would definitely put it in a database table.

**2 . Possibility of values changing :**

If these values are changing frequently and you want to give control to user maybe via an admin panel to manage these values, definitely store those in database table.

**3. The usage frequency :**

If these values are core of your system so that it's used in almost all queries to filter  the results, then you need to also account for the performance :

For example : Let's say entire project depends upon `High`, `Medium`, `Low` priorities. You need to filter almost every query using the priorities then :

Having Constants will have the `priority` stored in `tasks` table :

```
$tasks = Task::whereIn('priority', [high_constant, low_constant])->get();
```

Having a separate table `priorities` and having relationship will with `tasks` using `priority_id` foreign key have:

```
$task = Task::whereHas('priority', function($q){
    return $q->whereIn('priority_name', ['high', 'low']);
})->get();
```

Depending on number of data you have and frequent queries you do, you can check which is affecting performance. If the difference is very small, I would prefer constants with points 1 and 2 taken care of.

**4. Extras like Getting the ID :**

Let's say you have a page to create new task which has a dropdown of priorities.

If you have a separate table, you will have to get the ID of that priority from the `priorities` table to save it as a foreign key while saving task in `tasks` table. (Really not a huge deal though but good to mentioning)

If you have constant, you can save that value directly.

Each of it having pros and cons, I would make my choice mostly in point 1 and 2 above.

Also, if you are making constants, I would suggest to make a laravel [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) with a n alias and then have constants defined in it. So you can use it something like through out your project

`Priority::HIGH` or `Priority::LOW`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with the database and foreign keys. You are already hitting the database for the information, with a simple you you can grab the right value's instead of the id's.

But if its just these 2 lists... I'm not sure, i try to not use hardcoded value's
in my code to make easy changes without updating the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 2:

You can put it in an array in a seperate file, outside your code, so it would be easier to manage, like:

types.php

```
<?php
return ['type' => ['email','phone','text']];
```

And require it where you need it:

require '/types.php';

Store the array in a variable like $options
and use $options['type'] in your code.

Ofcourse you would need to push your code again. Other option would be caching it.